# Selecting, inserting, updating and deleting in a single query - possibly?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and have only very basic knowledge in SQL. Is it possible to create a single SQL query out of the following:

- Select all rows where `movedTo` is not empty
- Copy all these entries one by one into another table, but copying only a few columns as the other table does not have the same structure (let's assume that `serial` and `reason` are the same and `movedTo` should be inserted into `destination`
- Now overwrite the `region` column in the prior selected results with the content of the each `movedTo` column row by row
- Now empty the `movedTo` and e.g. `movedDate` column of all at the beginning selected rows.

I know how to do it in NoSQL, as I would just use for-loops, variables, JSON arrays and stuff, but I am lost realising it in SQL.

Hope someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Not in one statement but you can do this with 2-3 statements wrapped in a transaction. But you have to provide more details. What you describe as "Copy" is not clear if you want to do INSERT into the second table or UPDATE existing rows (of the 2nd table). Or both.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause in an UPDATE statement.

```
-- create some test tables

create table #sample(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key, 
    serial varchar(50), 
    reason varchar(50), 
    movedTo varchar(50), 
    region varchar(50), 
    movedDate date
    );

go

create table #sample2(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key, 
    serial varchar(50), 
    reason varchar(50), 
    destination varchar(50), 
    );

go

-- add some sample data
insert #sample(serial, reason, movedTo, region, movedDate)
select top(10) RTRIM(row_number() over( order by @@SPID)), newid(), newid(), null, GETDATE()
from sys.columns a;

go

-- perform the update/insert in one
update #sample 
set region = movedTo, movedTo = null, movedDate = null
output deleted.serial, deleted.reason, deleted.movedTo 
into #sample2(serial, reason, destination)
where movedTo is not null;

go

-- show the result
select *
from #sample;

select *
from #sample2;
```

Comment: This solution is not transactionally consistent. Please revise it with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.

Comment: The only statement that needs to be Is the update, which is. The rest is just framework to demonstrate.